# daimajia swipe view colliding with onClickListener on Android

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I used a daimajia swipe library to add a swipe view to a list in android. The swipe view works perfectly fine, however, it collides with the onClickListener() that I already implemented. whenever i swipe it works the onClicklistener(). I would like to know how I can stop the process of onClickListener while swiping?

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I am also stuck with the same.